# Countable Neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

How to prove it? Let $X$ be a topological space with base $B$ and $x \in X$. Show that, when $x$ has countable neighborhood basis, so there is a countable subset of $B$, which is a neighborhood basis of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{ U_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ be a countable local base at $x$, and the base for $X$ I will denote by $\mathcal{B}$.

For every $n$, we pick a $B_n \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_n \subset U_n$. This can be done by the definition of a base (e.g. every $U_n$ is a union of base elements, at least one of which contains $x$).

Then, $\{B_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subset \mathcal{B}$ is a (countable) local base at $x$ as well: let $O$ be open with $x \in O$, then for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \in U_m \subset O$, as the $U_n$ form a local base. Then by construction, $x \in B_m \subset U_m \subset O$, and we have some $B_n$ inside $O$ containing $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that the element of beighborhood basis is not a subset?

Comment: Yes. That's why I have a problem with this task.